# An error occured in the upload. Please try again later

Tags: wordpress

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3j3l.png)How to fix these errors when I'm trying to upload an image.

provide me s solution of this problem

Comment: add logs to your question (https://kinsta.com/knowledgebase/wordpress-error-log/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's outside the scope of Stack Overflow as defined in the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

You've got permission errors on your web server. Navigate to your webroot in terminal and change the folder and file permissions

```
find . -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;  
find . -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

Then make sure apache owns the wp-content folder: (Substitute your apache user. Its most often "apache" or "www-data")

```
chown <apache-user>:<apache-user> wp-content
```